# maven copy-dependencies fails on status 403 forbidden

Tags: maven, java-8, vaadin7

Project I'm working on uses Vaadin framework (old version 7) and java 8. Project is implemented as multiple projects (modules).
Everything worked fine for a few months until yesterday. I did some changes on 'core' part of the project, ran `mvn install` and jumped into the main project. There I ran

```
mvn clean
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

to get my changes and dependencies copied from core to the main project. Last goal (copy-dependencies) always fails with this error
(note that I covered some information in the error message on purpose):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< myproject.main >-------------------------
[INFO] Building Main version
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from mvn-repository jetty: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com/vaadin/addon/jpacontainer/3.1.1/jpacontainer-3.1.1.pom
Downloading from mvn-repository jetty: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com/vaadin/addon/vaadin-touchkit-agpl/3.0.0/vaadin-touchkit-agpl-3.0.0.pom
Downloading from mvn-repository jetty: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org/vaadin/resetbuttonfortextfield/1.2.1/resetbuttonfortextfield-1.2.1.pom
Downloading from mvn-repository jetty: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org/vaadin/addon/confirmdialog/2.1.2/confirmdialog-2.1.2.pom
Downloading from mvn-repository jetty: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/0.6.1/googlemaps-0.6.1.pom
Downloading from mvn-repository jetty: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org/vaadin/addons/contextmenu/4.5/contextmenu-4.5.pom
Downloading from mvn-repository jetty: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org/vaadin/addons/lazyquerycontainer/vaadin-lazyquerycontainer/7.3.3.6/vaadin-lazyquerycontainer-7.3.3.6.pom
Downloading from mvn-repository jetty: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org/vaadin/addons/popupbutton/2.6.0/popupbutton-2.6.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.383 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-17T11:37:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project main: Could not resolve dependencies for project *myproject.core:version*: Failed to collect dependencies at *myproject.core:version* -> com.vaadin.addon:jpacontainer:jar:3.1.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin.addon:jpacontainer:jar:3.1.1: Could not transfer artifact com.vaadin.addon:jpacontainer:pom:3.1.1 from/to mvn-repository jetty (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/): authorization failed for https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com/vaadin/addon/jpacontainer/3.1.1/jpacontainer-3.1.1.pom, status: 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The weird thing is that I don't know about any change in the project or my pc that could cause this issue.

I already tried:

- mvn -U dependency:copy-dependencies
- running mvn package on before trying to copy dependencies (fails with the same error)
- Resetting my Intellij environment
- Recompiling every dependent projects

I read the wiki article from the error message but I do not consider it to much use - project work before that without me having to set for example proxy or TLS. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't know where you have configured that `https://mvnrepository.com/` but this is no usable maven repository...simply it's wrong..remove configuration and use the defaults except you are in a corporate environment you have to use your internal repository manager

Comment: what is your pom.xml. As you need to update the URL, but there may be more to it, in case you use proxy or aliases. The goal `copy-dependencies` copies from `~/m2/repository/(...)` to a specific destination. If the package cannot be found locally or remote you get that specific error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed in the maven repository link. It seems that the dependencies have changed recently.

In my case the solution was to remove the repository in POM that caused trouble, namely

```
<repository>
  <id>mvn-repository jetty</id>
  <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/</url>
</repository>
```